# JWT not decoding

Tags: authentication, flask, jwt

I'm using JWT (the PyJWT library not the flask-jwt) for authentication in my Flask app, but it always returns in the binary form. I use jwt.decode() but to no avail. What am I doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,redirect,url_for,session
import model
import datetime
import os
from functools import wraps
import jwt


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.urandom(16)

def check_for_token(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args,**kwargs):
        token =request.args.get('token')
        if not token:
            return("ACCESS DENIED",403)
        try:
            data = jwt.decode(token,app.config["SECRET_KEY"])
        except:
            return("INVALID TOKEN",403)
        return func
    return wrapped


@app.route("/home",methods=["POST"])
def home():
    
    usrname = request.form["username"]
    psswrd = request.form["password"]
    valid_user = model.username_password_validation(usrname,psswrd)
    if not valid_user:
        return render_template("login.html",infoMsg="INVALID USERNAME/PASSWORD")
    else:
        session['username'] = usrname
        session['logged_in'] = True
        token =jwt.encode({'user':request.form['username'],'exp':datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)},app.config["SECRET_KEY"],algorithm='HS256')
        occupied_days = []
        user_id=model.get_user_id_from_username(usrname)
        tasks = model.get_all_tasks_for_user(user_id)
        for task in tasks:
            occupied_days.append({"day":task[3].day,"month":task[3].month})
            current_month = datetime.datetime.now().month
            days = model.get_number_of_days_for_selected_month(current_month)
            current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year 
            return render_template("home.html",username=usrname,tasks=tasks,current_month=current_month,current_year=current_year,days=days,occupied_days=occupied_days,token=token)


@app.route("/<string:username>/tasks?token=<string:token>",methods=["POST","GET"])
@check_for_token
def user_tasks(username,token):

    occupied_days= []
    token = jwt.decode(token,app.config["SECRET_KEY"],algorithms=['HS256'])
    user_id = model.get_user_id_from_username(username)
    tasks = model.get_all_tasks_for_user(user_id)
    for task in tasks:
        occupied_days.append({"day":task[3].day,"month":task[3].month})
    current_month = datetime.datetime.now().month
    days = model.get_number_of_days_for_selected_month(current_month)
    current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year 

    if request.method=="GET":
        return render_template("tasks.html",user_id=user_id,username=username,tasks=tasks,token=token)
    else:
        task_description=request.form['taskDescription']
        task_date=request.form['taskDate']
        model.update_existing_task(user_id,task_description,task_date)
        return render_template("home.html",infoMsg=f"task for {task_date} updated successfully",tasks=tasks,current_month=current_month,current_year=current_year,days=days,username=username,occupied_days=occupied_days,token=token)
```

here is the template file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jua&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    {% block title %}
    
    {% endblock %}
    <nav id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/home/{{username}}?token={{token}}"> Home </a></li>
            <li><a href="/{{username}}/tasks?token={{token}}">My tasks</a></li>
            <li><a href="/logout">Log out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    {% block content %}


    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Perharps I could pass it in the cookie instead of the query string , but I am not sure how that is done.

Comment: *but it always returns in the binary form* - what does that mean? What binary form? Can you show this non-decodable token?

Comment: in the query string i has b' in front of it like :

Comment: b'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoiYWwiLCJleHAiOjE1OTQwNzMwNjZ9.8dGZ_UHRJqizg0FqTE3ec4Lb3ngDFhV7XxKl10uv-_Y'

Comment: not sure where your token string turned into a bytearray, but you can turn it back to a string: `jwt = token.decode('ASCII')`. The token you have show is valid, a bytearray is just not the right form. So decoding it should help.